# How to return the created entity with MediatR

Tags: asp.net-core, mediatr

As per [Command Query Separation principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation), commands should return void.

I am using [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR/) Command Request Handler to create an entity as follows. So how can I get back the created entity?

```cs
public class CreateCompanyCommand : IRequest
{
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}

public class CreateCompanyHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateCompanyCommand>
{
  private readonly IRepository<Company> _repository;

  public CreateCompanyHandler(IRepository<Company> repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
  }

  public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateCompanyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var newCompany = new Company(request.Name);
    var createdItem = await _repository.AddAsync(newCompany);
    return Unit.Value;
  }
}
```

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57956631/1977871) as well as [its answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57957185/1977871), but I am still not clear.

How can I return the createdItem? What should be the Unit.Value? Can I modify and return something custom on my own instead of Unit.Value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want the created value back, you can change your request / handler to return it:

```cs
public class CreateCompanyCommand : IRequest<Company>
{
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}


public class CreateCompanyHandler : IRequestHandler<CreateCompanyCommand, Company>
{
  private readonly IRepository<Company> _repository;
    
  public CreateCompanyHandler(IRepository<Company> repository)
  {
    _repository = repository;
  }
    
  public async Task<Unit> Handle(CreateCompanyCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var newCompany = new Company(request.Name);
    var createdItem = await _repository.AddAsync(newCompany);
    return newCompany;
  }
}
```

There's nothing forcing you to *not* do this - commands aren't supposed to return anything in *pure* CQRS, but mediatr doesn't force this on you.

An alternative would be to create the id in the command (and initialize the id in the caller, or ctor of the command)

```cs
public class CreateCompanyCommand : IRequest<Company>
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Name { get; set; } = default!;
}
```

Call mediatr how you have in your question, then query for the Company you just created.